# Change powershell Title on every command

Tags: powershell

I would like to display the last command that i have entered into powershell in the title of the window so that it is easier to find

Currently I have:

```
C:\> $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle = $$
```

but this just gets the previous command relative to when i enter it so if I have

```
C:\> cd
C:\> $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle = $$
```

the title stays `cd` instead of changing with every command i give it. 
Is there a way I can set the title so it changes with every command I enter, ie

entering

```
 C:\> cd
```

will change it to `cd` and then

```
 C:\> python
```

will change it to `python`?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `$^` (the first token), not `$$` (the last token). It does matter for commands with parameters, e.g. `cd \temp`.

Comment: That gets the first token, but it only changes when I run the command - I guess my question is, is there a way to get the command [$host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle = $^] to run everytime i run any command in powershell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use your custom function `prompt` defined in your profile.
For example:

```
function prompt {
    # get the last command from history
    $command = Get-History -Count 1

    # set it to the window title
    if ($command) {
        $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle = $command
    }

    # specify your custom prompt, e.g. the default PowerShell:
    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}
```

Note: use of `$^` and `$$` in this function does not help, they are not yet set to the last command data.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. Just want to add how to find your profile: type `$PROFILE` to see the path to your PowerShell profile.

Comment: Wow, appreciate this great tip, Roman Kuzmin. I didn't know anything about the fact that the function name `prompt` provides this special feature. Can I ask you how you got to know this? I am asking that because I've never seen this info before, through all the times I've been searching and learning about PowerShell.

Comment: @SmartHumanism It's a well known but not prominently documented feature, I guess. I work a lot with PowerShell and read a lot about it. My chances to find out this at some point were very high :)

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I appreciate your reply. I wish you a good day and a good night!

Answer (score 2):

Roman's answer works, but it only changes the title *after* the command finishes (when the next prompt is displayed). In order to display the command while it's still running (say, for a long-running command like `ssh` or `sftp`), you'd need a different approach. Here's what I have working, added to my `$PROFILE`

```
# Set the console title to the currently running command
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Enter `
                         -BriefDescription RunWithTitle `
                         -LongDescription "Set the console title to the command, then run the command" `
                         -ScriptBlock {
    param($key, $arg)

    $line = $null
    $cursor = $null
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref]$line, [ref]$cursor)
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $line
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```