# Change PowerShell title to currently running command

Tags: powershell, title

I'd like to change the title of my powershell window to the currently running command. For example, I often have several PS windows open, each one running a continuous ping to a different host, and it would be handy to show which host is which in the title.

I can change the title *after* a command has been run using a function in the PS $profile based on Roman's excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211928/change-powershell-title-on-every-command). However, that function only runs when the command has completed and I'm back to the "PS C:\" prompt.

Basically, I'm trying to make it work the same way cmd.exe works out of the box:

[Default PowerShell Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNGNq.jpg)

[Default Cmd Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSjDG.jpg)

Comment: I've added an answer to the linked question. Essentially, what I found to work is overriding the Enter key to set the title before the command runs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75746187/338660